# No matching version found for are-we-there-yet@^3.0.0

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create my first Angular and using the command to instal Angular: `npm install -g @angular/cli`

But the terminal returns the following: No matching version found for `are-we-there-yet@^3.0.0.`

The latest version of `are-we-there-yet`. it's 2.0.0 (i used `npm view are-we-there-yet`) and I can't understand how the problem happens.

I've also used `npm install --save-dev are-we-there-yet@latest` to get the latest version and the latest is 2.0.0, now I'm lost.

Comment: Please provide logs from CLI/Terminal, might be useful

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of are-we-there-yet is: 3.0.0

check this npmjs information page:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/are-we-there-yet

tested with angular 14, npm install, installs the library without any issue,

In package.json file:

```
"are-we-there-yet": "^3.0.0"
```